# Como ejecutar una función de Azure Queue

Tags: c#, azure

Estoy trabajando con Azure WebJobs SDK 3.0, quiero ejecutar funciones sin necesidad de agregar mensajes en cola, simplemente el Web Job correrá continuo y que ejecute ese método

La firma de los métodos es así:

```
public async Task Registrar([QueueTrigger("registro")] Registro message, ILogger logger);
```

El método se activa al momento que se agrega mensaje en cola, pero quiero ejecutar métodos sin necesidad de agregar mensajes a la cola.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta ofrecida por Leandro?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo te refieres a esto

[Ejecución de tareas en segundo plano con WebJobs en Azure App Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

alli explica como crear un `WebJob` continuo, aunque en realidad no es que sea una ejecucion permanente, si la tarea termina tambien lo hara la ejecucion del job, pero se puede volver a lanzar

Quizas para que sea continuo el implementacion deba estar en un `loop` que no termine

Para crear este tipo de job debes seleccionar el `Type` como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues podras controlar su ejecucion pudiendo iniciarla o detenerla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]